# Default prop error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I created this utility to detect mobile using matchMedia.

I created a prop to manually adjust the breakpoint if needed. I defined the breakpoint prop as optional and gave a default value in the function.

For some reason I'm required to pass an empty object though when using the util?

```
OtherCompnent.tsx:
const { isMobile } = DetectMobile({});
```

If I remove the empty object I get the error:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
```

I'm fairly new to typescript and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, I feel like I should not need to pass the empty object and it should pick up on the default value for the breakpoint prop?

Here's the util:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

type DetectMobileProps = {
  breakpoint?: string;
};

export function DetectMobile({ breakpoint = "768px" }: DetectMobileProps) {
  const [isMobileDevice, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaWatcher = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${breakpoint})`);
    setIsMobile(mediaWatcher.matches);

    function updateIsMobile(event) {
      setIsMobile(event.matches);
    }

    if (mediaWatcher.addEventListener) {
      mediaWatcher.addEventListener("change", updateIsMobile);
    }
  }, []);

  const isMobile = useMemo(() => {
    return isMobileDevice;
  }, [isMobileDevice]);

  return {
    isMobile
  };
}
```

Any advice/help?

Comment: Not related to the question, but since this is a hook, [its name should start with `use`](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#hook-names-always-start-with-use), for example: `useDetectMobile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DetectMobile function requires a parameter because the props themselves are not optional.

If you wanted a truly optional prop, you'd have to do something like this:

```
export function DetectMobile(prop?: string) => {
   // rest of code
   // adjust "breakpoint" to "prop.breakpoint"
}
```

Comment: Or just `DetectMobile({ breakpoint = "768px" }: DetectMobileProps = {})`. Also no need for default export.